# Does Google Prettifier Supports Syntax highlightation of C#?

Tags: wmd, wmd-editor, pretty-print

I've started working on google prettifier to highlight the syntax. Just had a doubt whether google prettifier supports C# syntax highlightation or not. If yes, which .js file i need to include in my application?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), right?

From the documentation, it says it supports "C-like" languages, of which C# is one such language.

Comment: Thanks Dean, it helped me a lot. my doubt got clarified. thanks a lot.